# Virgin goddesses outside of the Greek and Roman traditions?

Tags: myth-identification, maiden-goddesses

The Greeks and Romans seem to have had something of an obsession with virgin goddesses, which seems somewhat counter to pagan traditions in general.  Who are some virgin goddesses *not* from Greek or Roman mythology?

Comment: Wikipedia has a whole category for Virgin goddesses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Virgin_goddesses

Comment: Are you more interested in chaste goddesses or virgin goddesses? Chastity and virginity are not the same, yet are similar in many regards.

Comment: @KenGraham Good point--one could be chaste but not be a virgin. (Question amended)

Comment: And Gefjon is apparantly a virgin, but in the story which she plays a major part, she is not chaste...

Answer (score 3):

Well, christianity is kinda famous for being considered non-pagan (at least by christians) and Mary being chaste. She is not technically a goddess, but is a mother to their God.

Comment: Mary is not considered a goddess by any Christian denomination as far as I am aware of.

Comment: @KenGraham Which is the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: I'll accept is as she is indeed venerated in certain traditions.

Comment: @DukeZhou Hello! I noticed that you wanted to accept the answer, but you didn't. Why? Do you need some additional information, or did you not find the way to do it?

Comment: I love this very short answer, but if I accept one answer, it would disincentivize additional answers, which I still hope to attract.  In many conceptions, mother Mary *is* the church, which imo gives her the stature of a goddess, particularly in denominations which venerate saints, semanic distinctions notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kumari The Virgin Goddess](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kumari-virgin-goddess-IDC940/) should be a plausible answer to your question! Whether this is a good fit here, it does remain interesting.

> The ancient practice of Kumari worship is vigorously alive today, deep in Nepal's Kathmandu Valley. A young virgin girl, Kumari, is selected as the embodiment of Goddess Taleju. A Kumari's dharma is to serve and bless the people. Her brief reign is a time of discipline and personal sacrifice.
>
> Among the most ancient of Hindu practices, Kumari puja (virgin worship) dates back at least 2,300 years to the late Vedic period. - [Nepal's Virgin Goddesses](https://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=4891)

The Kumari, according to the Wikipedia article is a real living virgin goddess:

> Kumari, or Kumari Devi, or Living Goddess – Nepal is the tradition of worshipping young pre-pubescent girls as manifestations of the divine female energy or devi in Hindu religious traditions. The word Kumari is derived from the Sanskrit Kaumarya, meaning "princess".
>
> In Nepal, a Kumari is a pre-pubescent girl selected from the Shakya caste or Bajracharya clan of the Nepalese Newari community. The Kumari is revered and worshiped by some of the country's Hindus as well as the Nepali Buddhists, though not the Tibetan Buddhists. While there are several Kumaris throughout Nepal, with some cities having several, the best known is the Royal Kumari of Kathmandu, and she lives in the Kumari Ghar, a palace in the center of the city. The selection process for her is especially rigorous. As of 2010, the Royal Kumari was Matina Shakya, aged four, installed in October 2008 by the Maoist government that replaced the monarchy. Unika Bajracharya, selected in April 2014 as the Kumari of Patan, is the second most important living goddess.
>
> In Nepal a Kumari is generally chosen for one day and worshipped accordingly on certain festivals like Navaratri or Durga Puja. In Kathmandu Valley this is a particularly prevalent practice.
>
> In Nepal, **a Kumari is believed to be the incarnation of Taleju**. When her first menstruation begins, it is believed that the goddess vacates her body. Serious illness or a major loss of blood from an injury are also causes for loss of deity. - [Kumari (goddess)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumari_(goddess))

[image: Samita Bajracharya]

> Samita Bajracharya is a 12-year-old Nepalese girl who lives with her family, studies hard, and enjoys playing a Nepali version of the lute. But until recently she was also worshipped by people who believed she was a reincarnated goddess. - [Nepal's living goddess who still has to do homework](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-27885141)